# Would a question about uploading images from Xbox be considered off topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I took a on my Xbox One this morning and I wanted to upload it to One Drive so I could share it with other people. But when I checked One Drive it said the video was a picture and not a video. I tried re-uploading it multiple times but the same thing happened every time.

Would a question asking how to fix this be considered off topic? On one hand it's about a feature on the Xbox but on the other hand it's also about One Drive which isn't really about video games.

Comment: It looks like the problem fixed itself after I gave it a day, I'm going to leave this question up however.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [xbox-one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-one):

> This tag should only be used if the question is about the Xbox One operating system or hardware, or a game feature truly unique to the Xbox One.

You question falls under "operating system" part, it's totally on-topic, and moreover it's encouraged in tag description.